# Bind object to FormGroup - ng2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an object contains data (for example: `orderDetails`) and I have `FormGroup` object bind to my object (`orderDetails`).

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(this.orderDetails);
```

I want to change the object (ex. `this.orderDetails.price = 15;`) and to see it in the formGroup and in the view.

*I can also access the formGroup `this.formGroup.controls['price'].setValue(15);` but it force me to write the field name without intellisense.*

Is there any way to synchronize between the object and the `formGroup`? 
Thanks!

Comment: how does it look in html?

Comment: <input type="text" formControlName="price"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` binding to automatically synchronize between the model and the control:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="price" [(ngModel)]="orderDetails.price">
```